# Faltering first steps with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to use `vue-route`r and I've fallen at the first hurdle. I have the following routes set up:

```
   const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: Home},
        {name:'product-list', path: '/product/list', component: ProductList},
        {name:'product-detail',path: '/product/:action/:id?', component: ProductDetail },
        {path: '*', component: NotFound }
    ]
});
```

When I enter the URL for one of these routes in my browser, though, such as `http://localhost:8090/product/list`, it makes a request to the server rather than handling it locally.

I've set my server up (it's `Grails` while in development) to redirect any `404` requests to '/', which is resulting in the Home component being displayed, as you'd expect from the routing. But I obviously want `/product/list` to bring up the `ProductList` component.

It's clear that I'm misunderstanding something fairly fundamental here. What is it, please?

Comment: Your router initialization looks okay, I can't see something strange here.The problem is maybe in your server configuration - https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: I was following those docs and I thought I was doing the server configuration right. I imagine it's here that my misunderstanding is. "If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in." Well, I'm doing that, I think, but it's serving the Home component, as I mentioned, not routing to '/product/list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting is no good because that tells the browser to change the url and retry the request.  You need to serve the same page for all requests that don't match a static resource.

This can be achieved by URL rewriting.  Please see your web servers URL rewriting documentation.

Comment: This was where I was going wrong, masked by another error in my code. Thanks!